# Mysql Workbench automatically refresh imported schema

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I do have two scheme's (2 .mwb files). One contains Users and such. The other contains the Core tables. Some of the Core tables should have relations with the Users scheme. However I can import the User scheme into the Core scheme and then create relations ("File" -> "Include Model"). But if I change something in the Users scheme then it won't sync with the Core scheme file. If I import the User scheme again it will not update, but create new double tables.

I hope you guys do understand what I am trying to accomplish here. I basically want the Users scheme to be standalone, but also be able to create relations in the Core scheme.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to maintain 2 different models if you need to create relationships between objects of both schemas? That would be the exact single reason **not** to keep 2 separate models. Unless one or both are huge it makes (almost) no difference to have both schemas in the same model file. You still have the schemas separate with their own objects.